# Jar- build with subdirectories but only include .class files

Tags: java, jar

In java I have a project whose directory structure looks like this

```
.
├── enderbyteprograms
│   ├── consolecolours.class
│   ├── consolecolours.java
│   ├── consolegames
│   │   ├── games
│   │   │   ├── Game.class
│   │   │   ├── Game.java
│   │   │   ├── guess_the_number.class
│   │   │   ├── guess_the_number.java
│   │   │   ├── testgame.class
│   │   │   └── testgame.java
│   │   ├── Main.class
│   │   ├── Main.java
│   │   ├── shared.class
│   │   └── shared.java
│   ├── enderlib.class
│   └── enderlib.java
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.mf
```

I am trying to build this in to a jar that only has the .class files.
`jar cvfm consolegames.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.mf enderbyteprograms/*.class` only includes the top level of classes, causing the program to complain about not finding the entry point. Building with `jar cvfm consolegames.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.mf enderbyteprograms/*` includes the subdirectories but also includes all of the assorted source files leading to unnecessary complexity. How to build a jar file that only includes *.class files but also includes the directory hierarchy? [jar 11.0.15]

EDIT 1:
The manifest file is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Enderbyte Programs
Main-Class: enderbyteprograms.consolegames.Main
```

Comment: Have you considered using a build tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)?  You're making your life way harder by doing this by hand.

Comment: "_but also includes all of the assorted source files_" – A solution to this is to specify a separate output directory when compiling your code (with `-d` when running `javac`).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your MANIFEST.mf has attribute Main-Class, if not add this attribute as below -

Main-Class: com.xyz.MainClass

Comment: The manifest file contains this attribute. ```Main-Class: enderbyteprograms.consolegames.Main```

Comment: The problem is not the missing manifest attribute. The problem is that by trying to filter to only include `*.class` files, not all class files are included recursively. One of those class files that doesn't get included is the main class.